# Getting a TCP/IP connection using Node-RED

Tags: tcp, node-red

I have two devices running Node-RED. I'm trying to send data from one to another using Node-RED. For that here's what I've  done :

the first device:

[image]

So the first one should just send the String "Testing" to the 2nd  with IP 100.
On the second here's what I've done:

[image]

The problem is I'm not receiving anything, despite port and IP address checks.

Does anybody has a hint about how to solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have configured both TCP (in and out) nodes to "connect" to the other.

This is wrong, you want to have the TCP-in node (on 192.168.178.10) configured to "Listen on"  port 80 and then have the TCP-out node (on 192.168.178.100) configured to "Connect to" port 80 on 192.168.178.100.